# WPF - MVVM: Duplicate all Models properties or expose the model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture

I've to start a fresh application and I'm currently asking myself if there is some kind of best-pratice on how to bind our model to the view through the ViewModel.

Currently, I see two options:

1. My ViewModel duplicates every field that has to be bound to the View
2. My ViewModel expose a Model object instance, on which the different properties of the ViewModel bounds.

What I can see:

**Duplicating the Model properties in the ViewModel**

Advantages:

- I keep a clear separation of concern between View and Model
- I can implement here all the validation mechanism

Disadvantages:

- It makes a LOT of code to duplicate(we create a new client for an existing solution, we have currently more than 1000 models)
- More code to write = more to maintain = more errors

**Exposing the Model properties in the ViewModel**

Advantages:

- The ViewModel will more focus on how to retrieve and save models
- ViewModels are cleaner to read
- This takes much less time to implement

Disadvantages:

- Not sure that the model is the best place for the data validation

So, any guidance you could provide me, or way of having both of the two world would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My opinion - it depends. Sometimes *routing* (exposing) Model instance as ViewModel property is enough (you have to handle property changed notifications still, e.g. Model has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or you can update **all** properties bindings at once with `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ModelInstance))`). But in general of course you have to wrap Model, even create ViewModel-only objects just to pass data between `View` <--> `Model` (via ViewModel). There is no *better* and you should use the most appropriate in concrete scenario method.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't duplicate the values required in the view model, but it does depend on how the model looks and how you want the view to look.  Create properties on the view model that wrap the model properties.

Comment: Currently ViewModels doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, doesn't have ObservableCollection

Answer (score -1):

@j4n  try to implement MODEL with **INotifyPropertyChanged**  and try to wrap continents of Model in class so you can use **observablecollection** in it . Use of observablecollection  reduce duplicate property